# Issue regarding Nested CASE statement in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server

here is my sql when i am trying to execute it then i am getting error msg **An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'then'.**

i am not being able to understand it where i am making mistake. so please have a look at my full sql specially where i use nested case and tell me what to rectify.

```
SELECT                 
        [bbajobs].[jid],                
        [Add Dates],    
    CASE WHEN 1 then 'Yes'      
        CASE WHEN 0 then 
            CASE WHEN job_flow_state.no_fault_found   = 1 THEN 'No fault found'         
            CASE WHEN job_flow_state.unable_to_repaired  = 1 THEN 'Unable to repair'       
            CASE WHEN job_flow_state.Repair_Not_Requested = 1 THEN 'Repair Not Requested'               
            ELSE 'N/A'  
        END  
    END AS [Repaired]
    FROM   bbajobs            
        LEFT JOIN ourfeedback                
        ON bbajobs.jid = ourfeedback.jid                
        INNER JOIN job_flow_state                
        ON bbajobs.jid = job_flow_state.jid                
        WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), bbajobs.jobshippeddate, 112) >='20140117'               
        AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), bbajobs.jobshippeddate, 112) <='20140117' AND bbajobs.jobstate IN ('DONE')                 
        AND bbajobs.jobtype NOT LIKE '%warranty%'                
        AND job_flow_state.repaired = 1             
  AND (ltrim(rtrim(ourfeedback.Rating))='' OR ltrim(rtrim(ourfeedback.Rating))='N/A') AND [bbajobs].[accountreference] IN                
  (SELECT accountref FROM ourfeedback where           
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ourfeedback.adddates, 112) >='20140117' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ourfeedback.adddates,112) <= '20140117'            
  )
```

### nested case used

```
CASE WHEN 1 then 'Yes'      
            CASE WHEN 0 then 
                CASE WHEN job_flow_state.no_fault_found   = 1 THEN 'No fault found'         
                CASE WHEN job_flow_state.unable_to_repaired  = 1 THEN 'Unable to repair'       
                CASE WHEN job_flow_state.Repair_Not_Requested = 1 THEN 'Repair Not Requested'               
                ELSE 'N/A'  
            END  
        END AS [Repaired]
```

Comment: You should specify what is `equal to 1 or 0 in your case statments`. Like `CASE WHEN Column = 1 then 'Yes'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got too many `CASE`s - you just need `WHEN`s in the inner nesting. You also need to switch on a predicate - i.e.  when 'what' is `1` or `0`. And lastly, you should consider what happens if the inner case doesn't match.

i.e.:

```
CASE SomeColumn 
     WHEN 1 then 'Yes'      
     WHEN 0 then 
        CASE WHEN job_flow_state.no_fault_found   = 1 THEN 'No fault found'
             WHEN job_flow_state.unable_to_repaired  = 1 THEN 'Unable to repair'
             WHEN job_flow_state.Repair_Not_Requested = 1 THEN 'Repair Not Requested'               
             ELSE 'Oops'
        END
     ELSE 'N/A'  
   END AS [Repaired];
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14687)

Comment: actually the sql i gave that was dynamic sql. so i am updating my sql please have a look. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd rewrite the nested case statement like so:

```
CASE WHEN 1 then 'Yes'      
     ELSE            
     CASE WHEN job_flow_state.no_fault_found = 1 THEN 'No fault found'         
          WHEN job_flow_state.unable_to_repaired = 1 THEN 'Unable to repair'       
          WHEN job_flow_state.Repair_Not_Requested = 1 THEN 'Repair Not Requested'               
          ELSE 'N/A'  
     END  
END AS [Repaired]
```